# Who is on the radio talking to/guiding the Falcon when Ant-Man goes to Avengers' HQ to steal Pym's prototype?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-2015

When Scott Lang goes to the supposedly SHIELD base to steal Hank Pym's prototype of a signal decoy, he finds out that it is now an Avengers' building. Falcon arrives as soon as Scott lands on the top of the building.

> **Scott Lang**: Alright I’m on the roof of the target building.
>
> **Hope van Dyne**: Somebody’s home, Scott. [just then Sam Wilson in his
>   Falcon flies in]
>
> **Voice over Radio**: [on Sam’s radio] What’s going on down there, Sam?
>
> **Scott Lang**: It’s the Falcon!
>
> **Sam Wilson**: [into his radio] I had a sensor trip but I’m not seeing
>   anything. Wait a second.
>
> **Dr. Hank Pym**: Abort, Scott! Abort now.
>
> **Scott Lang**: It’s okay, he can’t see me.
>
> **Sam Wilson**: I can see you.

**NOTE**: I recently read somewhere online that Sam was on comms with the Black Widow, which, I don't think is true. Because it wasn't a female voice on comms (let alone Scarlett Johannson's).

So who was on the comms talking to/guiding the Falcon during this heist?

Comment: “it wasn't a female voice on comms (let alone Scarlett Johannson's)” — does the voice on comms have any actually-audible dialogue?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite in the movie, it was audible  :P

Comment: It was! (Right around 1:02:56.) Unless Natasha’s doing a really good fake voice, it’s not her. Although we only hear that one line, right at the start. For all we know, Natasha got on the channel after that, and we just didn’t hear her speaking.

Answer (score 3):

[Peyton Reed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peyton_Reed), the director of the film, confirmed that it was indeed Natasha (Black Widow) in a [Tweet from a few days ago](https://twitter.com/MrPeytonReed/status/1256649421829238787):

> **@AnniBananniMixr**: @MrPeytonReed
>   I have a question for you, on 
>   @Antman
>   who was falcon talking too when he didn't want Cap finding out about him getting his butt kicked #Antman
>
> **@MrPeytonReed**: Great question. He’s talking to Natasha.

So the canonical answer would be Natasha, even if that seems unlikely.